# creating a new envionment in conda

Tags: anaconda, environment

I recently installed Anaconda on my laptop and when I tried to create an environment from a yml file, I keep getting this error:[image]

I've uninstalled and re-installed conda multiple times but the error still persists. I've even tried it older versions of conda in vain.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks!